# Saving string array in MongoDB - throws me a CastError

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, casting

I get a CastError when trying to save items to MongoDB using $each . I use FormData to send the array. If I display the array in the backend, everything is correct. I just can't store it in MongoDB

Frontend:

```
let array = ["ONE","TWO","THREE"]

let data = new FormData();
data.append("tags", JSON.stringify(array));
```

Backend:

```
const update = await newArt.updateOne(
  {
    $push: {
      tags: {
        $each: [JSON.parse(req.body.tags)],
      },
    },
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

> CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[
> 'ONE',
> 'TWO',
> 'THREE'
> ]" (type Array) at path "tags"

Schema:

```
tags: {
  type: [String],
  require: true
},
```

Comment: Try changing ` $each: [JSON.parse(req.body.tags)],` to  $each: JSON.parse(req.body.tags),` - without the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 arrays; one inside the `req.body.tags` and one around the `JSON.parse`, Try removing the external one:

```
const update = await newArt.updateOne(
  {
    $push: {
      tags: {
        $each: JSON.parse(req.body.tags),
      },
    },
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BEz16XOYC2i)